# SpringRoo GWT scaffold Maven dependency duplication error

Tags: java, spring, gwt, maven, spring-roo

I'm trying to go over this tutorial:

http://gwtsts.blogspot.sk/2011/03/part-ii-generating-gwt-project-using.html

because I need to know how to generate GWT front end from existing database (in my case Postgre but also this example will serve me well).

Here is my script from pizzashop.roo that I have executed:

```
project --topLevelPackage com.blogspot.gwtsts.pizzashop

persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE --applicationId pizzashopexample

enum type --class ~.shared.PaymentType
enum constant --name CC_ONLINE
enum constant --name CASH_ON_DELIVERY
enum constant --name CC_ON_DELIVERY

entity jpa --class ~.server.domain.Topping --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName name --notNull --sizeMin 2

entity jpa --class ~.server.domain.Base --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName name --notNull --sizeMin 2

entity jpa --class ~.server.domain.Pizza --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName name --notNull --sizeMin 2
field number --fieldName price --type java.lang.Float
field set --fieldName toppings --type ~.server.domain.Topping
field reference --fieldName base --type ~.server.domain.Base

entity jpa --class ~.server.domain.PizzaOrder --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName name --notNull --sizeMin 2
field string --fieldName address --sizeMax 30
field number --fieldName total --type java.lang.Float
field enum --fieldName paymentType --type ~.shared.PaymentType
field date --fieldName deliveryDate --type java.util.Date
field set --fieldName pizzas --type ~.server.domain.Pizza

gwt setup

logging setup --level INFO
```

Whole script was executed without any problems. But when I run command `perform tests` it gives me following error message(some dependencies were successfully downloaded but the build failed and ended with the error):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.datanucleus:maven-datanucleus-plugin:3.0.2:en
hance (default) on project pizzashop: Error executing DataNucleus tool org.datan
ucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer: InvocationTargetException: Plugin (Bundle)
"org.datanucleus.enhancer" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple
JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Users/jakub/
.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.1.0-m2/datanucleus-enhance
r-3.1.0-m2.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identic
al plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Users/jakub/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/da
tanucleus-enhancer/3.0.1/datanucleus-enhancer-3.0.1.jar." -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

I was trying the trick that I found here on stackoverflow to edit the pom.xml where datanucleus-core is located and concretely to add the tag `<scope>runtime</scope>` to datanucleus-core dependency but the result was the same.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit. Spring Roo 1.2.2, apache maven 3.0.3, spring tools suite 3.0.0, vfabric-tc-server-developer 2.7.1. I have set all system enviroment variables (JAVA_HOME, spring roo, maven).

Thank you very much for your help :)

My pom.xml:
[pom.xml](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51995533/pom.xml)

Comment: if read the error, it seems you have two instances of the same plugin jar (datanucleus-enhancer-3.0.1.jar) which are loaded from your local repository (one with version 3.1.0, the other 3.1.0-m2)

Comment: i tried to delete one of them but the error remains. How could I reconfigure it, or delete it not to have one there? I had new installation of maven with no repositories before creating this example.

Comment: the problem is in your pom.xml i suppose

Comment: I probably know where could be the problem. Is it possible that GWT jars have datanucleus inside and that Roo decided to insert in spite of this fact another dependency of datanucleus probably of a newer or older version?

Comment: try to run maven with "-X" option to see what package pulls in that datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.0-m2 dependency.

Comment: In your pom.xml, in the dependencies of maven-datanucleus-plugin, add an explicit dependency on datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.0-m2. This should solve the conflict but you should nevertheless understand why if was failing before.